# WebClient DownloadData - System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form

Tags: c#, path, directory, webclient

I'm using the following code in Winforms to download a txt file from an ftp site.  The code works, as I'm able to download the file, but I'm getting an exception.  My debugger is throwing the exception on the `DownloadData` function.

```
string versionInfoPathFTP = @"http://www.metoneftp.com/software/BCLoadCorr/version.txt";

private void check_FTP()
{
    string currentVersion;          //this programs version
    string latestVersion;           //newest version read from server

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    currentVersion = Application.ProductVersion.Replace(".*", "");

    try
    {
        byte[] newFileData = wc.DownloadData(versionInfoPathFTP);
        string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
        latestVersion = fileString;

        var latest = new Version(latestVersion);
        var current = new Version(currentVersion);

        var result = current.CompareTo(latest);

        if (result < 0)         //new version available
        {
            do_update_FTP(latestVersion);
        }
        else if (result == 0)   //at current latest version
        {
            labelInfo.Text = "Program is up to date! (" + latestVersion.ToString() + ")";
        }
        else                   //future version?
        {
            labelInfo.Text = "Current version is the latest!";
        }

        wc.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        labelInfo.Text = "No internet connection available!";
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is the exception being thrown:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetUri(String path)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
   at MetOneUpdater.UpdateControl.check_FTP() in J:\Products\Software\Automatic Software Updates\MetOneUpdater\MetOneUpdater\MetOneUpdater\UpdateControl.cs:line 65
```

Can anyone tell me why my URI is wrong?  or what I'm formatting incorrectly?  I've tried several different versions of the URI but they all throw an exception.  I tried getting rid of the `http://`, i tried getting rid of `www` but it doesn't seem to fix my issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `DownloadData` line throwing the error? The [MSDN page for this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't indicate that it can throw this exception. When I try your code I just get a `404` instead.

Comment: It sounds like you've missed some code out of the question where you then try and save the text file somewhere else and this is what throws the exception but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Pretty sure its `DownloadData` that is throwing the error.  Look at the stack trace, apparently it calls all that stuff.  Sorry about the filepath, that was an example filepath.  Try this one: `http://www.metoneftp.com/software/BCLoadCorr/version.txt`  I'm not saving the file anywhere, I basically read the version string from the file and use that to compare it to the current version of the program to determine if I need to update the program or not.

Comment: I've updated to show all my code.

Comment: I've tried with your updated code and cannot replicate the error. Unfortunately I have no other guesses about what's wrong.

Comment: When you try my code you don't get an exception?  Than it must be happening somewhere else.  Thanks for the clues, it will at least point me in a better direction.

Comment: I get absolutely no error at all, the string named `fileString` shows `1.3.0` as expected. I can't test the code after that where you compare and update versions as you didn't include it, but the problem is definitely not with the `WebClient`.